# Filtering one model based on another model's field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Post(models.Model):
    post_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_content = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Follow(models.Model):
    follow_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follow_target = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='follow_target')
```

I'm trying to create a queryset of all posts that were created by users I follow (me being the currently logged in user). My queryset currently looks like this but I keep getting NameError: field not found:

```
postresult = Post.objects.all().filter(post_user=follow__follow_target, follow__follow_user=request.user)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like part of [project 4](https://cs50.harvard.edu/web/2020/projects/4/network/#:~:text=Following:%20,signed%20in.) of Harvard/EdX's CS50Web syllabus. Thanks, this helps me too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You filter with:

```
postresult = Post.objects.filter(
    post_user__follow_target__follow_user=request.user
)
```

The `post_user` will follow the `ForeignKey` from `Post` to `User`. Then we use the `related_name='follow_target'` to follow the relation to the `Follow` object, and then we use `follow_user` to retrieve the following user.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from the `User` model to the `Follow`
> model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the
> same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the <s>`follow_target`</s> relation to `followers`.

In case you rename the related name, the query is thus:

```
postresult = Post.objects.filter(
    post_user__followers__follow_user=request.user
)
```

Comment: That worked wonders, thanks so much!

By the way, the additional related_name was added because Django couldn't create the field without a related name (something about a conflict with an existing relation, and the advice given was to create a related to name)